# WooCommerce add_to_cart metadata not sticking

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a WP noob but very comfortable in PHP.

I am working with a client and we have built a product customization tool as an Angular.js single page application.  When the product is finished being customized we are seeking to inject it into a WooCommerce cart so the client can check out.  To do this we are $_POSTing the data to a PHP file in the root directory of the WP install.  The code to catch it looks like:

```
require_once('./wp-load.php' );

global $woocommerce;

$woocommerce->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
$id_arr = $_GET['productID'];
$pdfName = $_GET['pdfName'];

for($i=0; $i<count($id_arr); $i++){
  $id = $id_arr[$i];
  if ($id==0) continue;
  if ($i==0){
    $ret = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($id, 1, '', '', array('pdfName'=>$pdfName));
  }else{
    $ret = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($id);
  }
}

wp_redirect(site_url().'/cart/');
```

The products are all correctly added to the cart but after checkout there is no sign of the metadata.  After extensive research, I have found an article here: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/woocommerce-add-to-cart-does-not-work-with-wpml-activated/ that shows me that plugins can cause this behavior.  So I have two specific questions?

1. Does my code make sense, am I creating the metadata array correctly?
2. Do I need to create something in WooCommerce called pdfName before I can do this?
3. Is there another way that metadata can be added to an order in
   WooCommerce that may work around this problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, `global $woocommerce` is deprecated in favor of `WC()`.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking.  Made that change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are adding the metadata correctly. However, as soon as you refresh, WooCommerce re-creates the cart data. Therefore you have to tell WooCommerce to maintain the metadata when it is pulling the cart from the stored session. Well, at least that is my understanding of it. So I think you need to filter thee `$cart_item` as it is run through the `woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session` filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'so_29660316_get_cart_item_from_session', 11, 2 );

function so_29660316_get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

    if ( isset( $values['pdfName'] ) ) {
            $cart_item['pdfName'] = $values['pdfName'];
    }
    return $cart_item;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, the function should be named so_29660316_get_cart_item_from_session, correct?

Comment: I suspect that the correct answer is something similar to what you have written here but with the change in my previous comment I am not seeing the pdfName value pass through to the order tables.